# Problems with implicit rule in make

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following directory structure

```
         (root)
  /      /      \        \
/       |       |         \
src    obj  include     bin
```

I would like to use an implicit rule to compile all the `.cc` files in `root\src` to `.o` files in `root\obj`.

This is my makefile so far:

```
basedir = .
incl = ${basedir}\include
obj = ${basedir}\obj
src = ${basedir}\src
lib = ${basedir}\lib
bin = ${basedir}\bin

CXX = gcc

LDLIBS = -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -lchipmunk -lSDL_ttf \
-lSDL_mixer

LDFLAGS = -L${lib}

objects = $(addprefix ${obj}\, GameObject.o PhysicalObject.o \
Terrain.o Timer.o main.o ImageLoader.o Player.o )

sources = $(addprefix ${src}\, GameObject.cc PhysicalObject.cc \
Terrain.cc Timer.cc main.cc ImageLoader.cc Player.cc )

Cyborg : ${objects}
    ${CXX} ${objects} -o ${bin}\Cyborg.exe -L${lib} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS}

${obj}\%.o : ${src}\%.c
    ${CXX} ${src}\$^ -c -o ${obj}\$@ 

.PHONY: clean

clean :
    rm ${bin}\Cyborg.exe ${objects}
```

The error that I get is `make: *** No rule to make target .\obj\GameObject.o, needed by Cyborg.  Stop.`

Any idea what's going wrong? I'm pretty new to makefiles so this might be terribly obvious.

Comment: Shouldn`t `${obj}\%.o : ${src}\%.c` be `${obj}\%.o : ${src}\%.cc`? Unless you want to compile in c.

Comment: What operating system (or version of make)?  It looks like you are using GNU make syntax but backslash as a directory separator, which seems strange

Comment: @Jesse Tried that. No luck. Same error.

Comment: @Nemo I'm using GNUWin32 make.exe

Comment: Does the `obj` directory exist?

Comment: Looks like windows. I think / works as a directory separator. It might be worth trying that because \ can escape things, for example the end of lines. I don't know if \% means something special or not.

Comment: @Oli Yeah, it's a subdirectory of the project root.

Comment: The `${CXX} ${src}\$^ -c -o ${obj}\$@` seems not right too: automatic variables `$^` and `$@` will have `${obj}` prefix, you are just making the file names like .\obj\.\obj\GameObject.o

Comment: @Pavel I removed the prefixes like you suggested. I also switched to windows / style path separators. I'm now getting: 

gcc: /src/GameObject.cc: No such file or directory

Comment: Try setting your variables to values like `obj\ ` (or `obj/` - for Unix style). Also make sure that you run make from your project root folder

Comment: Try `${CXX} $^ -c -o $@`

Comment: Just a hint: If you compile/link with `g++` instead of `gcc` then it will automatically pull in the `stdc++` library, as well as make sure include paths are setup correctly to find the standard C++ header files.

Comment: That last error message shows that make at least is now finding the source files and running the recipe, but gcc is looking in the root directory for the source file. Did you leave a stray `/` somewhere while editing the makefile?

Comment: If you invoke make as `make -d`, it will spew out a lot of debugging information describing what it is doing while it is processing rules (warning: it's a lot of output so redirect it to a file).  This output might show you if make is interpreting one of your rules differently than what you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying all of the ideas from the comments (and adding a couple trivial ones of my own), we get:

```
basedir = .
incl = ${basedir}/include
obj = ${basedir}/obj
src = ${basedir}/src
lib = ${basedir}/lib
bin = ${basedir}/bin

CXX = g++

LDLIBS = -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -lchipmunk -lSDL_ttf \
-lSDL_mixer

LDFLAGS = -L${lib}

objects = $(addprefix ${obj}/, GameObject.o PhysicalObject.o \
Terrain.o Timer.o main.o ImageLoader.o Player.o )

sources = $(addprefix ${src}/, GameObject.cc PhysicalObject.cc \
Terrain.cc Timer.cc main.cc ImageLoader.cc Player.cc )

Cyborg : ${objects}
    ${CXX} ${objects} -o ${bin}/Cyborg.exe -L${lib} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS}

${obj}/%.o : ${src}/%.c
    ${CXX} $^ -c -o $@ 

.PHONY: clean Cyborg

clean :
    rm -f ${bin}\Cyborg.exe ${objects}
```

What does "make Cyborg" do with this Makefile?

Comment: Some of this is unnecessary.  The setting of the "sources" variable is never used/needed, and it adds a second location where you have to update the list of sources.  What you should do instead is set "sources = GameObject.cc PhysicalObject.cc Terrain.cc Timer.cc main.cc ImageLoader.cc Player.cc" (just the files, no directory) then set "objects = $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(sources))" so you only have to list them one time.

Comment: Also having a target "Cyborg" where the rule uses "-o $(bin)/Cyborg.exe" is not right.  Make expects every rule to create a target with the exact name.  In this makefile, you will relink "$(bin)/Cyborg.exe" ever time you run make even if nothing needed to be done.  You should use first "Cyborg: $(bin)/Cyborg.exe" then for the link target use "$(bin)/Cyborg.exe: $(objects)" and in the link line use "-o $@".  This still lets you run "make Cyborg" but doesn't relink if nothing needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to take a few iterations.

Try some simple rules, in order of increasing complexity, and tell us the results:

```
./obj/GameObject.o : ./src/GameObject.cc
    @echo trying to build $@ from $<

./obj/GameObject.o : ./obj/%.o : ./src/%.cc
    @echo trying to build $@ from $<

$(objects) : ./obj/%.o : ./src/%.cc
    @echo trying to build $@ from $<

./obj/%.o : ./src/%.cc
    @echo trying to build $@ from $<
```

Answer (score 0):

```
${obj}\%.o : ${src}\%.c --> ${obj}\%.o : ${src}\%.cc
```

Answer (score -2):

I had similar problem with GNU make. Try making explisit rules for your objects:

```
$(obj)\GameObject.o: $(src)\GameObject.cc

$(obj)\PhysicalObject.o: $(src)\PhysicalObject.cc

# and so on for each object
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I would prefer to use implicit rules. I need to learn how to use them. Also, I will have many source files and I don't want to have an explicit rule for each one.